# Which webapp can I use to create a slider quiz/filter that is embeddable?

Tags: web-apps, survey

I want to present several sliders with two dimensions each to the visitors of my website. Each slider represents a scale, f.e. from 0 to 8. There are associated answer objects that should get displayed as a result of the slider settings.

I am looking for a small widget type web application that I can embed in my website. A jQuery solution such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10787027/jquery-price-slider-filter) is only second choice.

Example:
Let's consider you're looking for a new developer. You are looking for personality trait "single working" and "tech oriented".

You give the prospect a self-selection quiz where you ask him:

- Would you rather like to work alone or in a team?
- Would you prefer a tech or biz job?

If she puts her sliders in both answers above average, you would advice her to apply to two jobs (answers), that may be `<div>`s that you show or hide or just an answer that depends on the input.

Here is a graphical representation of such an app:

[image]